# whats wrong in this python lxml library

Tags: python, lxml

i am reading an xml file using xpath the issue its returning null.

**main**.py

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from util import xml_util

def main():

    try:
        xml = XMLReader('test.xml')
        x = xml.getitem('numbers/x')
    print x
        return 0
    except:
        return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

xml_util.py

```
from lxml import etree

class XMLReader:
    "Parse file and read data using find(path)"
    def __init__(self,fname):
        self.tree = etree.parse(fname)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

    def getitem(self,path,converter=str):
        return converter(self.root.find(path).text)

    def getlist(self,path,converter=str):
        return [converter(item.text) for item in self.root.find(path)]
```

test.xml

```
<mystuff>
   <numbers>
        <x>3.14</x>
        <y>42</y>
        <z>11</z>
   </numbers>
</mystuff>
```

The XMLReader class is received from this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357494/how-do-i-read-data-using-lxml-in-python

Comment: The code you show has indentation problems and incorrect imports. Could you please fix that?

Comment: i created a module named util and the xml_util.py has a class XMLReader so i used the import like from util import xml_util is that wrong?

Comment: @Kathick If `XMLReader` is defined in `xml_util` and you do `from util import xml_util`, you can't call `XMLReader` directly like you do in `main`. It'll cause a `NameError`, and the `except` clause will be executed.

Comment: from util.xml_util import XMLReader?

Comment: Yes. Also, if you want someone to read your comment, mention them with @username, and they'll be notified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from xml_util import XMLReader

def main():

    try:
        xml = XMLReader('test.xml')
        x = xml.getitem('numbers/x')
    print x
        return 0
    except:
        return -1


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

**Edit**

If you're still haveing problems and you set up a module with `__init__.py` and are trying to import xml_util then reference your reader `xml_util.XMLReader` or change your import statment to `from util.xml_util import XMLReader`

Comment: You should delete this, as it's just a copy/paste of code from the question.

Comment: @Gromer, really... look again.

Comment: Ah, you changed the import.  Carry on, sir!

Comment: @Kathick, if the code johnthexii didn't work for you, you should make sure your script is getting access to the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works for me.  I put this in a file called `main.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from lxml import etree

def main():

    try:
        xml = XMLReader('test.xml')
        x = xml.getitem('numbers/x')
        print x
        return 0
    except:
        return -1

class XMLReader:
    "Parse file and read data using find(path)"
    def __init__(self,fname):
        self.tree = etree.parse(fname)
        self.root = self.tree.getroot()

    def getitem(self,path,converter=str):
        return converter(self.root.find(path).text)

    def getlist(self,path,converter=str):
        return [converter(item.text) for item in self.root.find(path)]
```

In the **same** directory as `main.py`, I added `test.xml` with the XML you provided.

Shell:

```
$ ipython                                                                                                                          
Python 2.6.6 (r266:84292, Aug 28 2012, 10:55:56)                                                                                              

In [1]: from main import main                                                                                                                                           

In [2]: main()                                                                                                                                                            
3.14                                                                                                                                                                    
Out[2]: 0                                                                                                                                                               

In [3]:
```

It looks like you don't have `test.xml` where your script is looking for it.

As other's have pointed out, there were indentation issues in the code you put in your question.  I assumed it was a formatting issue after pasting the code in.  I tabbed the `print x` line in.

Also, it might be your `import` statement you have to import XMLReader.  Try changing `from util import xml_util` to `from xml_util import XMLReader`.